# Date format error with "2011-07-27T06:41:11+00:00"

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I'm trying to format a time/date string:

```
String date = "2011-07-27T06:41:11+00:00";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"); //2011-07-27T06:41:11+00:00
Date Sdate = formatter.parse(date.toString());
```

This is throwing the error

```
unable to parse newDate.
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, can someone explain?

Comment: How about using some semi-colons?

Comment: the answer is http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: String newDate = "2011-07-27T06:41:11+00:00"; DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");//2011-07-27T06:41:11+00:00

Date Sdate = formatter.parse(newDate.toString());

This is throwing unable to parse newDate. Please suggest..

Comment: @reporter: I don't think we should remove syntax errors from code by editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the TimeZone information. The ':' is an illegal character in the timezone string. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone and http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone

The following string is parseable

```
String date = "2011-07-27T06:41:11+0000";
```

Remove the ':' and your code will work.

Comment: no i have to parse that date... We are getting this date value from the feed

Comment: You will need to use a string replace to remove the extraneous ':' before passing to the formatter.

Comment: @Cintu : You can use a regex to format the date that fits your SimpleDateFormat pattern.

Comment: @Cintu: then you're doing it wrong. And "not working" is about the least amount of information that you could possible give about any given problem.

Comment: I m using this code now and it is working... I m able to parse..   date = (date.replace('T', ' ')).replace("+","###").split("###")[0]
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Comment: @Cintu: Now you are just ignoring the timezone information and either way I still believe my answer is the correct one. Not sure why you unaccepted it

Answer (score 1):

SimpleDateFormat do not accept all ISO8601 date-time formats .

You can use DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime in JAXB .

something like

```
String date = "2011-07-27T06:41:11+00:00";
Date Sdate = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(date).getTime();
```

and please do try to follow the conventions (variable names should start with a lower case)

Answer (score 0):

Try JodaTime. Java's built-in Date handling is not that good.