# Illegal argument exception while parsing date

Tags: android, parsing, datetime

How to parse this date format:

**Date:**

```
String previousTime = 2013-08-07T00:00:00.000-07:00
```

I tried,

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
currentDate = formatter.parseDateTime(previousTime);
```

But this is giving IllegalArgumentException,

```
08-22 18:31:41.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17300): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2013-08-07T00:00:00.000-07:00" is malformed at "-07:00"
08-22 18:31:41.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17300):    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:683)
```

Comment: Try this `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Answer (score 0):

Got from here: [Date format error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841067/date-format-error-with-2011-07-27t0641110000?rq=1).

The ':' is an illegal character in the timezone string.